# Dangerous driving: "queue de poisson" in Japanese?

Tags: word-choice, words

How to call it when a vehicle that just passed you gets back in lane too early, forcing you to brake, or even causing an accident?

See this [Diagram](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3a/Queue-de-poisson.svg).

This can also happen when a vehicle overtakes and then decide to turn very soon afterwards, cutting your way.

In French it is called [queue de poisson](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/queue_de_poisson).

It is DIFFERENT from "fishtail". Fishtail is when a vehicle loses control due to an obstacle, "queue de poisson" usually does not involve losing control, just braking in a straight line, in most cases. Fishtail can be had alone, "queue de poisson" can't happen with less than 2 vehicles.

Comment: In English, this is called *getting cut off* / *cutting someone off*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's just the phrasal verb "to cut off" in general, 割り込む works pretty well as its general translation. Its noun version is 割り込み. If you want to make it clear that someone cut you off dangerously close or suddenly, 無理 and 急 collocate very well. So, for example, in the noun case, 無理な割り込み sounds very natural, and in the verb case, 急に割り込まれる sounds fine.

Answer (score 1):

ALC proposes this:

> xxx cut me off : xxxが横から割り込んできた

Not sure it conveys the whole concept though.

Thanks to snailbot for helping me find this!